# Find the value of this sum.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac {2^n-4}{3^n}$$

I tried treating it as a geometric sum but I get 2 as the value, when it should be $\frac {10}{27}$

Comment: Did you first write the terms as $(2/3)^n -4\cdot (1/3)^n$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** This is not a geometric sum.  But, you can write it as two separate geometric sums (assuming that each will converge):

$$
\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-4}{3^n}=\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n}-\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\frac{4}{3^n}.
$$
From here, be careful to note that your first term ($a$, in the usual notation for geometric series) is when $n=5$ rather than $n=0$ or $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{3})^n-4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{3})^n-\sum_{n=0}^4 \frac{2^n-4}{3^n}$

$=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{4}{1-\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{91}{27}$

$=3-6+\frac{91}{27}$

$=\frac{10}{27}$

QED.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2^n-4}{3^n}\right)=\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n-4\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n=\frac{(2/3)^5}{1-(2/3)}-4\frac{(1/3)^5}{1-(1/3)}=10/27$$